# How well does Valgrind handle threads and machine-level synchronization instructions?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a highly parallel Windows program that uses lots of threads, hand-coded machine synchronization instructions, and home-rolled parallel-safe storage allocators.  Alas, the
storage management has a hole (not a synchonization hole in the allocators, 
I'm pretty sure) and I'd like to find it.
Valgrind has been suggested as a good tool for finding storage management errors.
Any experience here with Valgrind used under these circumstances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Valgrind does not run on Windows, but it does work with Windows programs running under Wine on Linux.  If your program will run under Wine, it has a decent chance of working with valgrind.  See [winehq.org](http://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_and_Valgrind) for details.

The latest version is pretty good at handling all the 32-bit x86 instructions.  It can handle programs that create many threads, just don't expect them to run simultaneously under valgrind.  It will run only one thread at a time, as if it was run on a single core machine.